# Extract individual elements of Arrays produced by Mongolite from a Dataframe

Tags: r, mongolite

I utilized Mongolite to download some MongoDB data. I stored it as a dataframe and then as a tibble as shown below:

```
aggregate = as.data.frame(aggregate)
aggregate = as_tibble(aggregate)

duplicates_removed = aggregate %>% distinct(plot, title, released, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

However, I now desire to extract individual elements from arrays. However, RStudio has converted these arrays into textual form. For example, an Array containing "Short" and "Western" has been turned into `c("Short", "Western")`.

For the purposes of processing such as the usage of the `count` function, I need to be able to count individual elements, not combinations. How do I do this?

This is what I tried initially:
`count(duplicates_removed, vars = duplicates_removed$genres)`
Shown below are the results:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: It's not clear from that image if `vars` contains `"c(\"Short\", \"Western\")"` (one string with escaped quotes) or if it is a list-column.

Comment: Can you post the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]? It's unambiguous and will answer several questions.

Comment: @r2evans
Here is the requested code:
```genres_table = count(duplicates_removed, vars = duplicates_removed$genres)
dput(head(genres_table))```
The output of the above code is:
```structure(list(vars = list("Short", c("Short", "Western"), c("Short", 
"Drama", "Fantasy"), c("Animation", "Short", "Comedy"), c("Drama", 
"History"), "Fantasy"), n = c(27L, 2L, 5L, 57L, 143L, 13L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))```

Comment: (1) If you want counts of individual elements _before_ your call to `count(.)`, it might be more helpful to have a sample of _that_ data. (2) Comments can be skipped, please put relevant data like that in the original question (in a code block please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have list-columns. While it would likely be better to do the counting right the first time, we can heal from your first call to `count` with:

```r
genres_table %>%
  tidyr::unnest(vars) %>%
  summarize(n = sum(n), .by = vars) # dplyr_1.1.0 or later
# # A tibble: 7 × 2
#   vars          n
#   <chr>     <int>
# 1 Short        91
# 2 Western       2
# 3 Drama       148
# 4 Fantasy      18
# 5 Animation    57
# 6 Comedy       57
# 7 History     143
```